# Sql view combining columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, union

How would i make a view or calculated table that would take this.
table 1

```
location   send1T   state send2TF   state 
west         T       WA     F        OR
east         F       FL     T        NY
central      T       ND     T        TX
```

And would make a view or table that looks like this if send 1 or send 2 is true.

```
location  state
west        WA
east        NY
central     ND
central     TX
```

Comment: Probably, you're looking for `UNION`.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It would of course be preferable to fix your bad data model and normalize your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the following (Postgres):

```
create view myview (location, state) as
(select location, state1 from table1 where send1T = true)
union
(select location, state2 from table1 where send2tf = true);
```

Note that your original table included state twice, I called it state1 and state2 respectively. The creates/inserts for testing:

```
create table table1 (location varchar, send1T boolean, state1 varchar, send2tf boolean, state2 varchar);
insert into table1 values ('west', true, 'WA', false, 'OR');
insert into table1 values ('east', false, 'FL', true, 'NY');
insert into table1 values ('central', true, 'ND', true, 'TX');
```